# How to correct an ellipse looking circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

With this code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[tick label style={font=\scriptsize},axis y line=middle,axis x line=middle,name=myplot,axis on top, 
            xtick={-1,1}, 
            ytick={-1,1}, 
            ymin=-1.1,ymax=1.1,%
            xmin=-1.1,xmax=1.1%
] 
\addplot [blue,domain=0:360,thick,smooth,samples=40] ({cos(x)},{sin(x)}); 
\end{axis}
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following output

[image]

which looks an ellipse. Any correction to my code to get a better circle looking figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify width and height of axis. You might change 5cm to any value, of course.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5cm,height=5cm,tick label style={font=\scriptsize},axis y line=middle,axis x line=middle,name=myplot,axis on top, 
            xtick={-1,1}, 
            ytick={-1,1}, 
            ymin=-1.1,ymax=1.1,%
            xmin=-1.1,xmax=1.1%
] 
\addplot [blue,domain=0:360,thick,smooth,samples=40] ({cos(x)},{sin(x)}); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

While setting the height and width works, it would probably be better to set `axis equal`, which means that the unit length is the same for both x- and y-axis.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
   axis y line=middle,
   axis x line=middle,
   name=myplot,
   axis on top, 
   xtick={-1,1}, 
   ytick={-1,1}, 
   ymin=-1.1,ymax=1.1,
   xmin=-1.1,xmax=1.1,
   axis equal         %% <-- 
] 
\addplot [blue,domain=0:360,thick,smooth,samples=40] ({cos(x)},{sin(x)}); 
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```